# Qt widgets in a library

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to create a library(.so file), which will have methods

1. Create_widget (Which will create a widget in the library code)
2. Add/modify widget (QPixmap or QGraphicItem)

The caller code :
testFile.cpp will call the Create_widget of the library and the expectation is it will create the widget. Then add/modify(add_Image_to_widget) methods will called from testFile.cpp and expects a update on the widget.

```
TEST_F(SomeTests, Check1)
{
    int argc = 0;
    char* argv[0] = {};
    QApplication qapp(argc, argv);
    Create_widget();
    sleep(5);
    add_Image_to_widget();
    sleep(5);
    qapp.exec();
}
```

The problem :
Until the qpp.exec() is called the GUI will not show any update. This seems the behavior as explained in qt doc.

My expectation is as soon as Create_widget called widget needs to be created and after sleep of 5 seconds, image to be displayed. But in this case the event processing starts only after exec. (Blocking call).

Let me know how this can be achieved.

Tried to move the below operation to a thread

"
`QApplication qapp(argc, argv); qpp.exec();`
"

This made the errors of widget not created in QApplication.

Comment: What if you use something like `QTimer::singleShot(5000, ...);` (use the correct arguments)?